# May a constant inside a function, as input, be removed and placed in front of the function?

Tags: calculus

Take, for example, $$P=f(Cx)$$ Where $P$ is some unknown value, $C$ is a known constant positive integer, and $x$ is a positive variable. I really want to do this, $$P=Cf(x)$$
But I'm somewhat certain that's not allowed.  Can anyone say something about the first expression? I want to get that constant out.

Comment: It stretches (or contracts) the function *horizontally*; multiplying $f(x)$ by $C$ would stretch (or contract) vertically. Algebraically, for a generic function, there isn't much we can say.

Comment: @pjs36 I should also have added that C is known.

Comment: NO NO NO.  It is almost always false that $f(Cx) = Cf(x)$.  For example, if $f(x) = \sin x$, then certainly $\sin (5 x) \ne 5 \sin x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true in general.

Example: $$f(x) = x^2 + 1 \\ f(5x) = (5x)^2 + 1 = 25x^2 + 1 \\ \color{red}{5f(x)} = 5(x^2+1) = 5x^2 + 5 \color{red}{\ne} 25x^2 + 1 = \color{red}{f(5x)}$$

In the special cases where this is true we would say that $f$ is *homogeneous*.

Example of a homogeneous function: Any line though the origin.  $$f(x) = mx \\ f(5x) = m(5x) = 5mx \\ \color{red}{5f(x)} = 5(mx) \color{red}{=} 5mx = \color{red}{f(5x)}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  I've gone through my calculations over and over trying to figure out what's wrong. Now I know!

Comment: So, kind friend, if my function is always homogeneous, then I may remove the constant and place it in front of my function.

Comment: That's right.  Not all functions are homogeneous though, so don't just assume the function you're working with is until you've proven it.

Comment: In this case $f$ is homogenous *of degree 1*. There are more general variants of homogeneous: if $f(cx) = c^k f(x)$ then $f$ is still said to be homogeneous (of degree $k$).